# MDADM: Unable to grow raid-6 with journal?

Tags: raid, mdadm, journaling

In the past, I expanded/reshaped raid-6 arrays multiple times with mdadm.
Today I've added 2 disks to new raid-6 array, and was not able to reshape it.

It was different this time: now with journal and under WSL2 / Ubuntu. Is there a workaround or I am missing something?

```
root@DESKTOP:~# mdadm -v --grow --raid-devices=7 /dev/md0
mdadm: Cannot set device shape for /dev/md0: Invalid argument
```

Array details:

```
root@DESKTOP:~# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Thu Nov  3 01:14:38 2022
        Raid Level : raid6
        Array Size : 5860144128 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 1953381376 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
      Raid Devices : 5
     Total Devices : 8
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Fri Nov  4 02:26:35 2022
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 5    Working Devices : 8
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 2

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

        Consistency Policy : journal

              Name : DESKTOP:0  (local to host DESKTOP)
              UUID : 21b70607:7ca3faf8:af74d21e:caa06133
            Events : 26489

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       3       8       65        3      active sync   /dev/sde1
       4       8       81        4      active sync   /dev/sdf1

       5       7        1        -      journal   /dev/loop1
       6       8      129        -      spare   /dev/sdi1
       7       8      113        -      spare   /dev/sdh1
```

> root@DESKTOP:~# uname -a Linux DESKTOP
> 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

mdadm - v4.1 - 2018-10-01

Answer (score 3):

Yep, growing raid-6 with journal is not supported, at least by mdadm 4.1

You can:

1. --fail and remove journal device
2. echo resync > /sys/block/md0/md/consistency_policy"
3. add external bitmap
4. grow array
5. re-add journal

Comment: This was a life-saver! I figured out looking in the kernel's source code that the journal was what was preventing me from resizing an array. But after failing and removing the journal device, the consistency policy was still "journal" and "mdadm --grow" wouldn't let me change it. Doing it manually via sysfs worked. Thanks a ton!